# C++ Function and Class Template declaration

Tags: c++, function, templates, arraylist, constructor

Right now I am trying to see why arrayList is coming up as an error, I am not sure if it was because I didn't create an arrayList object properly because the error I would be receiving is "arrayList not declared. Here is one or two lines of my code with the constructor definition and declaration. Really appreciate if someone could help. Can someone tell me if I had created the arrayList Object correctly in the main program?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type> //Template class declaration. This needs to be here to be able to define the class templated. 

class arrayList

{

public:

arrayList<Type>::arrayList(Type size = 100);
                               //constructor
                               //Creates an array of size specified by the parameter
                               //size. The default array size is 100.
};

template<typename Type>
arrayList<Type>::arrayList(Type size)
{
    if(size < 0)
    {
        cout<<"The array size must be positive. Creating " << "an array of size 100. "<<endl;

        maxSize = 100;
    }
    else
       maxSize = size;

    length = 0;
    list = new int[maxSize];
}

//CONSTRUCTOR: Basically the size is capped off to 100 items, but user can add any number of items up to 100.

int main()
{
int num;//Numbers that will be prompted from the user 
int alternative; //New number to be added to the list 
int newnumber; //Used to be added in the arraylist
int newlocation;


    arrayList test; //This will be the tester Arraylist to test the methods
}
```

Comment: Looks like a few things wrong - can you provide the actual compile errors as well as the code? PS - why are you using your template type to define the array size?

Answer (score 1):

you should not prepend

```
arrayList<Type>::
```

when declaring the constructor in the class-definition.

also, provide complete error messages, things like line numbers can help alot

when you use the type, you need to provide the template paramerer, as in

```
arrayList<short> mylist;
```

Comment: to be specific is the line that is arrayList test; //This will be the tester Arraylist to test the methods